# Дублированные параметры в HTTP GET запросе

Tags: java, spring, http, rest, get

Разбираюсь с REST, пишу приложение на спринге. Интересует такой вопрос, можно ли сделать так, что бы дублированные параметры запроса, пример: `?tag=one&tag=two`, считывался например как строка, разделенная запятыми. Я в своём методе параметры запросы считываю вот так `@RequestParam Map<String, String> parameters`, и тогда в параметре `tag` будет лежать значение, указанное первым, в нашем случае `one`. Собственно, можно ли как-то изменить это поведение ?

Comment: А вариант `@RequestParam("tag") List<String> tags` устроит, если работает?

Comment: можно также воспользоваться `@RequestParam MultiValueMap<String, String> requestParams` [пример](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-web-mvc/mapping-multi-valued-query-parameter.html)